# Force on moon & what will happen next?

Tags: forces, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics

The moon is rotating around the earth. It is feeling a force by earth due to gravity. So if I some how manage to exert some force into moon, what is be the scenerio? I can think of:

1. The moon will go further away from the earth.
2. The moon will speed up.

But what will exactly happen?

It will be good if anyone gives a mathematical explanation.

Comment: That depends very much on the direction of that force.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on direction of  force , its magnitude and escape velocity for the moon to escape from that point against gravitational  field. If the direction of force is parallel to its velocity it will speed up and its orbit's radius increases. If force is perpendicular then the potential energy of moon rises due to increase in distance from earth. This will impart high velocity when the moon approach earth thus resulting in increased orbital radius. If velocity goes beyond  escape velocity then moon will escape from earth's gravitational influence.

Comment: vishnu Bharar Can you give me the mathematical explanation? I understand in that way well. But thanks for your answer.